# View data dictionary overriding model data in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have a view to create a user as follows.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("SaveUser", "Security")) {%>
    <p>
        <label for="UserName">UserName:</label>
        <%= Html.TextBox("UserName") %>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessage("UserName", "*") %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="Password">Password:</label>
        <%= Html.TextBox("Password") %>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Password", "*") %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
<}%>
```

When the "Create" button is clicked, the HTML form is posted to an action called "SaveUser" that accepts the "POST" verb only as follows.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult SaveUser( UserViewModel user)
{
    //user.Id is zero before save
    //Save the user.  Code omitted...
    //user.Id is now greater than zero
    //redirect to edit user view
    return View("EditUser", user );
}
```

After the user is saved, the page is redirected to the "EditUser" view with

```
<p>
    <label for="Id">Id:</label>
    <%= Html.Hidden("Id", Model.Id)%>
</p>
```

Here is the problem: the value for the hidden field kept showing up as zero though. `Model.Id` is greater than zero.  It seemed that something else is overriding the model view value.  `ViewDataDictonary` was a suspect.  So a line is added before returning the view in the action as follows.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult SaveUser( UserViewModel user)
{
    //user.Id is zero before save
    //Save the user.  Code omitted...
    //user.Id is now greater than zero

    //clear the view data
    ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary();
    //redirect to edit user view
    return View( "EditUser", user);
}
```

Sure enough, this worked.  The hidden field now has a value of the correct user ID.

**We found a way to treat the symptom, but where is the source of the problem?**

I don't like the idea of clearing view data dictionary every time before a returning another view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After successful operation you should use

```
return RedirectToAction("EditUser", new { id = user.Id });
```

or similar code. The current ModelState is used to generate view and model binder didn't bind Id.

`[Bind(Exclude = "Id")]` could also work, but the redirection creates new page (not using current ModelState) and is a better solution.

**Edit:**

If you don't want to bind whole object, you should use `[Bind (Exclude)]` or you should just define `SaveUser` as `SaveUser(string userName, string password)` and build the `UserViewModel` object yourself. This will save you from errors generated by model binder and Model values, that you don't know where come from.

Comment: ++, this is the preferred way of handling this. It also solves the problem of the user refreshing the page and inadvertently re-posting the same form post.  Depending on the system, that could be a bad thing if your action isn't idempotent.

Comment: @LukLed, @Joel: thanks guys for the helpful.
My UserViewModel is more complex than I posted here so I've written custom model binder.  A friend of mine found a way to use the default binder without the custom one so I'll work on switching to it.

Comment: @LukLed: after using RedirectToAction, the problem still occurred and I had to use ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary();  In other words, using redirecting is not solving the problem.  Is there something I'm missing?