# Is it normal that inputs (generated by html helpers) are influenced by POST data?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, post, view

In a MVC app we implemented a mini forum. New posts in this forum are ajaxed. The AJAX POST action either returns a response form (partial view) or new post html and form html as a JSON.
New post and form are both rendered from views by [this method](https://gist.github.com/cassioeskelsen/831567). The model provided for the form has some null values, but the corresponding inputs store values taken from POST data (I verified the generated data to make sure it's not something that is done by the browser). The inputs are generated by html helpers (such as `TextBoxFor`).

So my question is, is this normal behavior in MVC and if it is, then how do I go about making those inputs have empty/null values (or even some specific value)? When debugging the values in the model are exactly as I set them (which is null, but same thing happens for any value really), but inputs for this very model still hold values taken from POST data.

I tested how does this work with good old `PartialView` instead of rendering html to string and returning it through JSON, but the results were exactly the same (so the method I use for rendering those views should be unrelated to the problem).

---

I came across this question: [View data dictionary overriding model data in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560579/view-data-dictionary-overriding-model-data-in-asp-net-mvc)

But from what I checked in my app, the POST data isn't actually stored in `ViewData` and the OP wasn't AJAXing data so redirects made more sense in his case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this [post](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Apr/20/ASPNET-MVC-Postbacks-and-HtmlHelper-Controls-ignoring-Model-Changes) which explain this problem in detail and shows ways to deal with it.

To sum it up. Yes, this is normal behavior of htmlHelpers during POST action. To prevent it you can run `ModelState.Clear();` in your post action (preferably just before you return\render the view). Optionally it is also possible to remove just one field using `ModelState.Remove("PropName");` where `PropName` is the name of the model property which you don't want to be passed from POST data.